# Vehicle Drive Model - wheel and engine angular speed approach

Tags: simulations

I am trying to create a **simple** car simulation in 2D in Unity3D, I'm having a hard time figuring out the right approach.

Say I have given the throttle percentage, I know the current engine's and wheels' angular speed and car's speed. Say, the car is moving on a flat ground, in a straight line.

I can calculate the engine's torque (by using a polynomial for example) as a function of throttle percentage and current engine's angular speed.

Say I calculate all the way through the transmission system to the driving wheels.
I have the torque at the driving axle.

I want to understand these two things:

1. **How to calculate the new angular speed of the driving wheel?**
2. **How to calculate the new angular speed of the engine?**

I mean, I have the torque, now what? :D
Should I use the friction coefficient wheel-to-ground?
How should I approach these problems?

Having those speeds I could then use something like Pacejka to calculate forces at driving wheels, and rolling resistance factor to calculate forces at non-driving wheels and create my small, simple simulator, but I cant wrap my head around the two problems I presented.

Please provide any of those:

- explanations,
- good reads, forums, books, articles,
- videos or courses on the subject,
- ready simulations so I can compare results,
- words of encouragement :-D